# Use np.nan without importing numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am used to replacing empty string with NaN and dropping to remove empty data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df.replace('', np.nan).dropna()
```

However, I want my function to run using serverless framework. I need to `import numpy` just to use `np.nan`, which eats up my precious 250MB limit for package size.

Importing `pd.np.nan` works, but there is warning that `pandas.np` module is deprecated and will be removed from a future version of pandas.

Is there any solution to use `np.nan` **without importing numpy**?

Comment: It is unlikely that NumPy will just be removed from Pandas' dependencies. You can use `pd.np.nan` without importing anything.

Comment: @norok2 Hell hath frozen over: _"FutureWarning: The pandas.np module is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Import numpy directly instead"_

Comment: @xtian I guess they were waiting for me to write that comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `pd.NA` instead.

From [the Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#experimental-na-scalar-to-denote-missing-values):

> Starting from pandas 1.0, an experimental `pd.NA` value (singleton) is available to represent scalar missing values. At this moment, it is used in the nullable integer, boolean and dedicated string data types as the missing value indicator. The goal of `pd.NA` is provide a “missing” indicator that can be used consistently across data types (instead of `np.nan`, `None` or `pd.NaT` depending on the data type).

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps you can get away with `math`:

```
import math


math.nan
# nan
```

or even without importing anything:

```
float('nan')
# nan
```

These are compatible with NumPy's `nan`:

```
import numpy as np


np.isnan(math.nan)
# True

np.isnan(float('nan'))
# True
```

Comment: Worth also noting that `type(math.nan) is type(np.nan)` - there really is no difference between them, other than the fact that they are not two names for the same object, `id(math.nan) is not id(np.nan)`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but `df.replace('', None).dropna()` should work, right?